# JQuery fadeIn vs show method difference

Tags: jquery

Is there any real different between JQuery fadeIn() and show() methods implementation wise? of course other than the fact that fadeIn has that animation thing going on. I'm asking this question because I'm seeing a weird behavior.

I have some backbone views in which I'm creating an image tag and loading them. When I want to show them, they work on fadeIn() but not on show(). So is it the problem with my code or the way JQuery implements it.

Comment: It's rarely ever a bug with whatever libraries you use (but not impossible). Can you recreate it in an environment like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: It might not be a bug, by saying fadeIn you are not promising similar implementation to show method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calling `show` without passing any arguments is equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'block')`.  If your `opacity` is set to `0` you still won't see the element.

However, according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> When a duration, a plain object, or a "complete" function is provided, .show() becomes an animation method. The .show() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously.

So, if you want `.show` to behave like `.fadeIn`, you'll need to pass a parameter to it.

Comment: you are right on!! the opacity is 0 not sure what sets it to 0 though. Thank you

Comment: @sublime It has tripped me up in the past, too. :)